# gRPC fails when service method called from Android SyncAdapter

Tags: android, grpc

It took me some time to figure out that below error is caused only when I try to use gRPC client from SyncAdapter:

```
No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp or grpc-netty artifact
```

The setup is exactly like in official tutorial [Transferring Data Using Sync Adapters](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html).

I've generated gRPC code using same setup as an [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/android) from grpc-java. The `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'` dependency in example is not necessary as `compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:0.9.0'` was modified to be self contained.

When the gRPC service method is called from the main activity it works fine.

I suspect that the `grpc-okhttp` must be initialized in some way but have no clue how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've decided to read the code of gRPC. The code I've used to create channel was:

```
mChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(mHost, mPort)
        .usePlaintext(true).build();
```

The way the generic ManagedChannelBuilder class works is to dynamically load all classes extending `ManageChannelBoulder` and choose the one with highest priority. Then the chosen class is remembered in static variable.

It seems that during a call in `SyncAdapter` the appropriate builder for okhttp was not available. I've fixed it by hardcoding the choosen builder:

```
mChannel = OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress(mHost, mPort)
        .usePlaintext(true).build();
```

I hope to save someone's evening.

Comment: Using `OkHttpChannelBuilder` directly is an acceptable workaround. Commonly the problem is caused by ProGuard or similar removing what appears to be an unused class. Doing `-keep class io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider` in ProGuard may fix the problem.